# zsh completion list-colors - partial colouring issue

Tags: colors, zsh, tab-completion

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152157/how-does-the-zsh-list-colors-syntax-work I wanted to have a different colour for the per-match descriptions in the menu list, but I can't get it to work in all cases.

Example of the issue:
[image: with colour]

vs

[image: NO colour]

More examples & tests can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/Orangenhain/c9ac6ea47f187589813b9887c300a897

Answer (score 4):

Quoting a very helpful zsh-users mailing list [post](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2017/msg00334.html):

> [...] list-colors patterns have to be able to
>   properly color completions (alone), descriptions (alone but with lots
>   of trailing whitespace), or single lines consisting of a completion
>   followed by a description.

More in-depth information is in that post.

The following **list-colors** definition works (in this case):

`zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors '=(#b)*(XX *)=32=31' '=*=32'`

[image: success]